# Need some explanation about asynchronous tasks

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous

Here is one of the things I understand the least with iOS programming. When I push a view with my navigation controller, I need to read a text file with a huge amount of data that takes around 2-3 seconds to process, while creating the new view.

So I want to process this file asynchronously, in order to show an ActivityIndicator at the same time.

I have already used, in other projects, connection functions (`connection`, `connectionDidFinishLoading`...), but here what I want to do is different because data is already in my project files, so connection is not needed.

Thanks for your help and advices.

Comment: you could read text-file in background thread( dispatch_async ) , then call a callback method on main thread , also it will be good if you provide some loading/activity indicator that something is going on back there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Asynchronous call (as I'm sure you're already know), is something that is being called on a separate thread, while the main thread continues onward. Objective-C operates this way because if the call were made synchronously, then the UI (and everything else for that matter) would simply hang until the data is loaded.

Alright, so to do this in Objective-C, you need to have some kind of method that queries your data. In the event that it's pre-loaded in Core Data or SQLite, it's more or less the same kind of method that gets called.

There are a ton of ways you can handle this. I prefer blocks, because of their simplicity.

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[User loginWithBlock:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"response object (the data): %@", responseObject);
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

FYI, MBProgressHUD is the activity indicator.

So, let's break this down. The activity indicator is allocated, and displayed in the view, and will remain until the block is called, which won't be called until the task of loading the data is completed. Once the data is finished loading, the block sends the responseObject (your data), and hides the activity indicator.

Simple as that!

**EDIT:**

This is really more of an add-on, but whatever.

To answer your comment below, to make the call or handle the "data processing", that `loginWithBlock:` function is built out as it's own function.

```
+ (void)loginWithBlock:(ObjectResultBlock)block
{
    [[APIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"login" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         if (block) block(responseObject, nil);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         if (block) block(nil, error);
     }];
}
```

With the declaration of the block in the header file of where you created this function:

```
typedef void(^ObjectResultBlock)(id responseObject, NSError *error);
```

This particular example is using AFNetworking. But as I stated before, it's all going to look relatively the same across the board.

So, let's break this down...

`loginWithBlock:` is called, so you perform the APIClient call, which either succeeds, or fails. In a perfect world, it succeeds, and you then pass the responseObject through the block.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, and last thing I want to know where is or should be the function that corresponds to my data processing in this piece of code? It's the `loginWithBlock` function, simply?

Comment: No problem. Blocks seem kinds daunting at first, but they're freaking awesome once you have the hang of them. :) Best of luck!